# I want to install Expression blend for Visual studio 2012 on my Win7 machine. how to get it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I have Expression blend 4 on my computer. I found some guys talking about Expression blend for Visual studio 2012.

Can I got it on my Windows 7 machine. I don't thing for WP8,7 or store apps. I only want do Silverlight development.

if Expression blend for visual studio 2012 available then how I can got it. I search a lot on google but thing make me confused.

one more thing is  how I can got it. I don't want to have VS pro or above on my PC. I have express VS 12.

Answer (score 1):

Expression Blend for Visual Studio 2012 is only available for Visual Studio 2012 Professional and above.

Visit this link: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare

Comment: There is an entry for "Blend" on this page and it shows it available on almost every version.

Comment: It doesn't available in Express version, and the asker use Express version. What is the point of your comment? Please elaborate.