# Where to download Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

The path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries
```

contains several libraries that are available on any of our developer machines (Win7, VS 2012 Premium).

Creating a project that references any of these files works on developer machines, but results in troubles on our build server.

I'd like to avoid workarounds like moving thise files in our CVS system or those nuget-wrapper-packages.

Hence, where can I download the MS Blend 4.5 SDK. 
(Found the link for Framework 4.0, but not for Framework **4.5**)

Answer (score 3):

It does not appear to be available as a separate install.  It is available as an installation option with Visual Studio 2012 Professional and above based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820109/i-want-to-install-expression-blend-for-visual-studio-2012-on-my-win7-machine-ho).